# changing the file's last modified time through touch() and getting the result with filemtime()

Tags: php, caching

So I'm trying to get the file's last modified date and then update it to the current time, but when I look at the result I get the SAME timestamp in both $oldtime and $newtime

```
$file = 'test.txt';
$oldtime = filemtime($file);
touch($file, time());
$newtime = filemtime($file);

echo '<h1>old</h1>';
print_r(getdate($oldtime));
echo '<h1>new</h1>';
print_r(getdate($newtime));
```

Comment: maybe you don´t have sufficient rights, check the return value of touch.

Comment: Are you running linux on the server ? 
touch() works only under Windows as per the documentation.

Comment: @KAbhishek what documentation? `touch()` was not working under windows until php 5.3.0, and it wal always working under other OS

Comment: @K - touch() should work under all main operating systems, not just under Windows; and I can't find anything in the docs that says "Windows only"

Comment: Sorry, read it wrong.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use [`clearstatcache`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.clearstatcache.php) after `touch`ing file to get proper value of modification time.

Because you have used `filemtime` before, result for it was cached, and on second call, result is pulled from that cache instead of checking file directly.